# AJAX Request Body Empty (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, node.js

I am trying to solve this problem without using jQuery so that I can have a better understanding of how things work.

I am sending an AJAX request to a node server with a JSON object. The server can receive the request and respond but the request body is always empty. I have tried setting the request header to 'application/json' but for some reason this changes the form submission to POST the parameters to the URL, rather than use the Javascript function. If anyone could tell me why that is happening as well it would be much appreciated.

**Form**

```
<form onsubmit="sendEmail(); return false;">
  <input type="text" name="fromEmail">
  <input type="text" name="subject">
  <textarea name="message" rows="14"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

**Email Function**

```
function sendEmail() {

  var emailContent = JSON.stringify( 
    {
      email: $('input[name=fromEmail]').val(),
      subject: $('input[name=subject]').val(),
      message: $('textarea[name=message]').val()
    }
  );

  var httpRequest;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, IE7+ ...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE 6 and older
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  httpRequest.open('POST','/message', true);
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
      alert(httpRequest.responseText);
    }
  }

  httpRequest.send(emailContent);
}
```

**Node JS Routing**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

// set body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Process email form
app.post('/message', function(req,res) {
  console.log('Request received by email path.');  
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('{"success": true}')
  console.log('Response sent.')
});
```

Comment: Open up the Developer Tools on your browser, check if there's any console errors and check on the Network tab if the request is being sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood your problem, what you need is to call the function sendEmail() without doing a postback. Well, for this you will nead a regular html button instead of a form submit. Forms are used to execute server requests to an specific url and generate another postback.

You have two options:

1) Do a client side call using a button and an ajax request (XMLHttpRequest):

```
<input type="text" name="fromEmail">
<input type="text" name="subject">
<textarea name="message" rows="14"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="SEND">
<button type="button" onclick="sendEmail()">Send</button>
```

2) Use a form submit and call the service directly form the form. The parameters will be taken from the form and will be sent in the request:

```
<form action="/message" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fromEmail">
  <input type="text" name="subject">
  <textarea name="message" rows="14"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="SEND">
</form>
```

Then in the server side you can access the data using the names you gave to the fields:

```
fromEmail = req["fromEmail"]
```

Comment: I think this was my problem. The form was submitting via URL encoding and not using the sendEmail() function. This along with setting the content type fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to send json response, you need to set the content type of response as json.

```
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
httpRequest.open('POST','/message', true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
httpRequest.send(emailContent);
```

Reference:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp